# Is there a free hosting that supports new TLDs?

Tags: domains, looking-for-hosting, top-level-domains

I can't find a free hosting that supports new gTLDs. On my opinion, these are really good hosting providers: freehosting io, 2freehosting.com and even there I get an error when I try to create an account to use hosting service.[image]

**EDIT:** I registered a new gTLD on GoDaddy and tried to create a new account on those service providers. Still have the same error.

Comment: Register the TLD separately...

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards, did it and it doesn't work.

Comment: I can't help you with 'it doesn't work'...

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards, sorry, I mean I registered a new gTLD on GoDaddy and tried to create a new account on those service providers and still have the same error.

Comment: If you registered a gTLD on GoDaddy, you don't need to register that domain at your free hosting provider. You will need to update the DNS of your GoDaddy domain to point to your free hosting provider.

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards, probably I wrote a confusing comment. Well, I try to sign up for a free hosting with my new gTLD. And some hosting services don't support new gTLDs. Here is a support letter from one of them: `Unfortunately, we currently do not support .center domains. We may take a look at accepting those domains in the future.`. Thank you for your help, I have just found the one that suports new gTLDs. It is: **www.hostinger.co.uk**

Comment: If you're looking for free hosting I'd go for Hostinger too. They are quite reliable, for both their free and premium services in my experience with them.